# extract value for calculated attribute

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

within Rails4, the following logic determines an attribute

```
if @items.count == 1
  value = "disc1"
elsif @items.count == 2
  value = "disc2"
else
end
```

which would then need to be accessed

```
@cluster.value
```

however this syntax does not work as the value is not a method. How can this variable be employed to extract the object's thus-named attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you just conditionally call methods:

```
if @items.count == 1
 @cluster.disc1
elsif @items.count == 2
  @cluster.disc2
else
  # ...
end
```

---

Still, if you want to go that route:

```
@cluster.public_send value
```

---

Or if `@cluster` is an `ActiveRecord` model and you want to fetch the stored value in the corresponding table, you could:

```
@cluster[value]
```